# how to list all updates made on a specific webpage?

Tags: python, screen-scraping

Here is my goal : each time a new market is created on a specific page ( for instance https://www.winamax.fr/paris-sportifs/match/21514495) of this website "www.winamax.fr" I would like to list the new additions by date. Is it to possible to do this by using python scraping techniques ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. When you scrape the page, save the results in a file or database. Then the next time, compare the results with what you saved.

Comment: Which language would you recommend ? If there are any links that you can share I will take it. Thanks

Comment: If the page is static HTML, use Beautiful Soup. If the page is dynamic with JavaScript updating the contents, use Selenium WebDriver. These are the most common tools for web scraping.